# Not able to download a file with NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsmutabledata

I am just new in IOS development. I've been trying to figure apple documentations. So I read this page:

[http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple%5fref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE)

and this is what I have done:

```
NSMutableData *testFileType;
// Create the request.
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                              timeoutInterval:60.0];
// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    testFileType = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSLog(@"the connection is successful");
} else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
    NSLog(@"the connection is unsuccessful");
}

[testFileType setLength:0];
[testFileType appendData:[NSMutableData data]];
```

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: I know NSData, it's not what I want.

Comment: By the way, my apologies for suggesting you check out the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE). Re-reading your question, you were complaining about how opaque that document was, so it wasn't appropriate to suggest you read (again!) that doc. Apple's docs take a little to get used to, but that comment wasn't terribly constructive. Sorry. I've deleted that comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just creating the NSURLConnection is not enough. You also need to implement the didReceiveResponse and didFinishLoading delegate methods. Without these the connection downloads the file, but you never get to see it.

NSURLConnection sends a didReceiveResponse for every redirection when the headers are received. Then it sends a didReceiveData with some bytes of the file. Those you need to append to your mutable data. Finally you get a didFinishLoading where you know that you have gotten all data. In case of error you get a didFailWithError instead.

Look at the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I actually don't need to save the file to the hard drive. All I need is to be able to have it in an instance variable.

Also I thought that last two lines are actually fetching data???

Comment: Updated my answer with clarificarions

Comment: are there any actual samples as a project file for xcode? I couldn't find it and I am still trying to get used to apple's documentation style...

Comment: By the way, if you go to the iOS version of that `NSURLConnectionDelegate` doc, you'll see scary references to the key methods being deprecated. That's because Apple has moved these methods to [`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

you should implement the following delegate methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %d %@", [error code], [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    responseData = [NSMutableData data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [responseData writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES]; 
}
```

here responseData and savePath are instance variables declared with:

```
NSMutableData *responseData;
NSString *savePath;
```

and your class must conforms the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocols.

For the code to work you probably want to set savePath to a working path like this

```
NSString *savePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testfile.txt"];
```

after the download have finished, you can do anything to the file at `savePath` as you wish.